# How to get referenced obj mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose

So I'm building a web app and using mongodb _ mongoose, I chose this db because I have used it before, and it was a very easy and fast to get rapped up on. I am now running into some use cases where I think a relational database would be a better. But I am here to find out if I can find a fix using mongo db before I rip out all my DB code for mongo.

I have three collections, one of users and one of pending jobs and one of completed jobs. I need to run a pending job, then delete it from the collection and create a completed job entry. Both job collections are connected to a user via an object ID reference list field on my user model. I know how I can get all the pending and completed jobs for a specific user.

```js
const resp = await User.findOne({username:username}).populate(['pendingJobs', 'completedJobs'])
```

But How do I get the user of a specific job?

- EDIT

Pending Jobs Model

```js
const pendingJobModel = new mongoose.Schema({
    date:{type:String, required: true, unique:true},
    startTime:{type:String, required: true},
    endTime:{type:String, required: true},
    courseList:{type:[String], required: true},
    member:{type:String},
    clubUsername:{type:String, required: true},
    clubPassword:{type:{token:String, iv:String}, required:true},
    proxy:{type:Boolean, required: true, default:false},
    active:{type:Boolean, required: true, default:false},
},{collection:'pendingjobs'})

module.exports = mongoose.model('PendingJob', pendingJobModel)
```

Completed Jobs Model

```js
const completedJobModel = new mongoose.Schema({
    date:{type:String, required: true, unique:true},
    successful:{type:String, required: true},
    time:{type:String},
    course:{type:String},
    member:{type:String},
},{collection:'completedjobs'})

module.exports = mongoose.model('CompletedJob', completedJobModel)
```

User Model

```js
const userModel = new mongoose.Schema({
    username:{type:String, required: true, unique:true},
    password:{type:String, required: true,},
    refreshToken:{type:String, default: ''},
    proxyConfig:{type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId, ref:'Proxy'},
    pendingJobs:{type: [mongoose.Types.ObjectId], ref:'PendingJob'},
    completedJobs:{type: [mongoose.Types.ObjectId], ref:'CompletedJob'}
},{collection:'users'})

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userModel)
```

Thanks SO peeps for the help in advanced!!

Comment: please provide examples from your pending jobs collection.

Comment: Example of what? A document?? @barrypicker

Comment: Can you provide schema models for all 3 collections?

Comment: I added the models @NeNaD

Comment: Is member the same thing as user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just query user based on the `pendingJobs`/`completedJobs` properties:

```js
const user = await User.findOne({ pendingJobs: pending_job_id });

...

const user = await User.findOne({ completedJobs: complited_job_id });
```

Comment: Yea thats not the problem I'm having I didnt include this in my question but I export the models with those names so it works.

Comment: I am trying to get the associated user of a particular job document like a backwards lookup.

Comment: I updated my answer. Can you check it again?

Comment: Nice preciate it, I feel dumb for how simple it looks now lol.